# How do I use Twig to create raw, working html URL's in a Drupal 8 View?

Tags: drupal, view, twig, field

**The Problem**
From within a custom view template I'm trying to output a twig variable as raw data inside a `<a href="">` tag but it does not output anything?

**What I have tried**
I've tried using the Twig Tweak plugin, following the instructions on their cheat sheet (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x)  but that doesn't work. I've also tried printing it out like so

```
{{ fields.buy_now_link.content | raw }}
```

but with no luck.

This Stack Overflow article ([Acces raw data in Drupal 8 view template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061025/acces-raw-data-in-drupal-8-view-template)) provides a solution by setting their own variable in the theme file but that seems a bit long-winded and cumbersome?

**This is what I have**
In Drupal 8 I have a content type called Albums, which has a 'Plain Text' field called 'Buy Now Link'. Here the user enters a URL which is just a plain text string like this:

```
/music/album/buy-now.html
```

I have added a view for this field and created a custom view template called **views-view-fields--music-album.html.twig** and I am trying to print the field out as raw data like so:

```
<a href="{{ fields.buy_now_link.content }}">Buy Now</a>
```

The problem is that when I view this in the browser it shows nothing at all. However if I print it outside of the `<a>` tags, then it works perfectly fine.

**The Expected Results**
The expected results for this process would be as follows:

```
<a href="{{ fields.buy_now_link.content }}">Buy Now</a>
```

to print out like this in the browser:

```
<a href="/music/album/buy-now.html ">Buy Now</a>
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question. It's as simple as taking the variable that you want and appending it with the ***striptag*** filter.

To keep things readable you could add a variable. For example.

If my twig variable is `{{ fields.buy_now_link.content }}`

Then I will use that to set a custom variable using my own identifier such as *myURL*

`{% set myURL = fields.buy_now_link.content %}`

Then I can use that two different ways:

**Option one:**

`{{ myURL|striptags }}`

**or option two:**

```
{% filter|striptags %}
        {{ myURL.content }}
{% endfilter %}
```

**Finally**
Now we can do something like this:

`<a href="{{ myURL }}">Buy Now</a>`

If option one doesn't work for you, try option two.